# How should I budget encounter XP for a single PC?

Tags: dnd-4e, encounter-design, experience-points, group-scaling

[In the photo I've shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BnuT.png), it starts the XP budget for a party of 4 PCs. At 1st level, the budget is 400. For 5 PCs it's 500. And 600 XP for 6 PCs.

So I guess it's safe to assume that I can divide the XP budget for four PCs by 4 to get the XP for one PC?

Because the XP for one PC, according to the progression of this chart, would be 100. And 100 is the answer to 400 XP ÷ by 4 PCs.

How should I budget encounter XP for a single PC? Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and check out [how to ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) when you get a chance. Your initial question is a good one, and something this site can answer. However you go on to ask about general tips and request feedback. This site is not a forum and questions like that will get closed as too broad. Try to reduce this to the single problem you are trying to solve and give an example of your approach to solving it. We should be able to answer that. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Also we prefer if you use quote blocks to reference source material rather than linked screenshots. Remember to reference where you got that table from so we can give a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A budget is both the total amount available to you and how you should spend it.

So, **yes, your assumption is correct** about the linear nature of the XP budget for encounters.

> **Target XP Reward**, *p.57 DMG*
>
> To find your total XP budget, multiply the number of characters in the party by the XP value of a monster whose level is equal to the encounter level you chose.

The encounter level isn't necessarily equal to the character level; normal encounters are party level or level+1, hard ones are higher, easy ones are lower. I believe you can step down to 75/50 XP for a "level 0" or "level -1" encounter.

The problem is that spending this budget **on a single monster** is going to be stone-boring. 4E is an active tactical game, not a cat-and-mouse simulator. Later advice in the DMG2 (pp. 50-51) suggests you keep the total number of monsters about the same as you would for a 4-5 player party, no matter your party size, for this reason.

Does that mean the first couple levels are just going to be Minion Town? Well, not necessarily. You might want to consider:

- **Level 0 monsters**. Just step back a level 1 monster's attacks, defenses, and damage by 1 point and knock a handful of points of HP as appropriate by role. A level 0 monster and 2 level 1 minions is 125 XP, a fairly even-level encounter for a level 1.
- **Companions.** Mentioned in the first DMG, they get a more extensive treatment in DMG2 starting at page 27. A companion is basically a friendly monster (including "monsters" like the listed entries for dwarves and humans) that basically contributes its total XP to every encounter's XP budget and gets it back as a share from combat, meaning the total amount of XP awarded per encounter doesn't change. A companion of your solo PC's level basically gives you 2 PCs' worth of budget for every encounter, which is a little more leeway to spend on interesting setups.

And, like p.57 of the DMG also suggests, try and keep the level range of the monsters you put in the combat within four or five levels of the PCs. Otherwise the numbers are going to slope too strongly one way or the other to be worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was super helpful.

Comment: @JaceOxburn Thanks! Glad I could help. You can click the checkmark by the answer to indicate to anybody else who lands on this page that it worked for you, the person who asked the question.